# Convert PostgreSQL dump file to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to convert a PostgreSQL dump file I received to a MYSQL dump file or even sql text to be generated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you install the PostgreSQL client programs, you can use "pg_restore" to convert a dump file to a SQL script without having to have a PostgreSQL instance. Just do `pg_restore dumpfile.pg` and it will print the restore SQL to stdout.

Comment: which PostgreSQL client program is best?

Comment: well, pg_restore is one of the cli utilities supplied with postgresql. I generally use psql for working with the server. Some people really like pgadmin, I don't to the extent I'm trying to write my own desktop client. ymmv.

Comment: For anyone using bash who would like to save the output to file, use: pg_restore dumpfile.pg > my_file.sql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ?? the OP wanted to convert a PostgreSQL dump file to something else. The default operation mode of pg_restore is to read a dump file and convert it to plain SQL. Although MySQL can't read that directly, it's at least then in a state to be hacked by script etc.

Answer (score 8):

If you have PostgreSQL installed on your terminal and your file is `latest.dump` you just need to convert it to `latest.sql` this way:

`$ pg_restore latest.dump > latest.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Check this link ... probably of help

http://www.weberp.org/HowToConvert

Also, check this links

http://dbconvert.com/convert-mysql-to-postgresql-pro.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884060/is-there-a-free-tool-to-convert-mysql-dump-to-postgres

Answer (score 0):

A [**google search**](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&site=webhp&source=hp&q=postgresql+dump+file+mysql&pbx=1&oq=PostgreSQL+dump+file+&aq=1v&aqi=g-v2g-b2&aql=&gs_sm=c&gs_upl=0l0l1l4728l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=8bad52dc14d635c1&biw=635&bih=276) yielded a reference to [**this discussion**](http://www.dbforums.com/postgresql/787445-postgresql-mysql-conversion.html). It looks hopeful and maybe it will help.

HTH